# How do I add some default parameters when using RestKit and RKObjectManager?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ios, devise, restkit

I'm using RestKit, RKObjectManager, and, server side, devise for authentication. I need to send my authentication token on every request. Is there a way I can easily add it for all requests?

Currently, for GETs, I'm doing the following:

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/%i", [self pluralizedName], identifier];
path = [path stringByAppendingQueryParameters:[self appendAuthenticationToken:params]];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:path delegate:delegate];
```

This works great. However, for PUTs, I tried the following:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] putObject:resource usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {
    loader.delegate = delegate;
    loader.params = [RKParams paramsWithDictionary:[self appendAuthenticationToken:params]];
}];
```

This correctly sent my authentication token, but the server didn't receive the resource I was trying to update. Does anyone know the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the first time I have seen a authentication token appended to a path like this. You can't add it to the headers? I have a feeling that is the more standard way of doing it.

If you do it this way, you can use [RKClient setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:] on the client supplied by your RKObjectManager.

Comment: This is actually what I ended up doing. On the server side, I pull the token from the headers and put it in the params.

Comment: Curious about how to something similar in RestKit 2.0 ?

Comment: On your RKObjectManager object there is a HTTPClient property which is your AFHTTPClient hook. So you can do something like: [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].HTTPClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:password:]. Look in AFHTTPClient for more details.

Answer (score 0):

In RestKit .2, you would address this issue as:

```
 [[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] HTTPClient] setAuthorizationHeaderWithToken:self.user.token];
```