# RestKit - Appending a parameter to all requests

Tags: iphone, objective-c, restkit

I have an iOS app using RestKit in order to communicate with a RESTful Rails server. The server uses a basic session token for authentication of users. I want to append this token to every request sent using the RKObjectManager's methods.

I've tried creating a Category overload of NSManagedObject in order to use the following method:

```
- (void)willSendWithObjectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader
```

That works fine, however I see no way of appending to the object loader's params. I've even gone as far as to reserialize the object but there is no way to do that without it being sent using escape characters. For example, the following code will give me the object in JSON serialized form

```
RKObjectMapping *serializationMapping = [[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] mappingProvider] serializationMappingForClass:[self class]];
RKObjectSerializer *ser = [RKObjectSerializer serializerWithObject:self mapping:serializationMapping];
NSObject<RKRequestSerializable> *obj = [ser serializationForMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON error:nil];
```

But the object returned there is intend to be used as a param right away so the following code does not work

```
[params setValue:[LCSingletonLoggedInUser sharedLoggedInUser].sessionToken forParam:@"token"];
[params setData:obj.HTTPBody forParam:@"data"];
```

I've also tried various combinations of setObject and setData and obj.HTTPBody as well as just obj right away.

Actually appending obj to params in any way will always result in it adding escape characters which the server can't handle. Setting params = obj will give the correct values to the server but won't include the token.

Comment: I have answered the same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455427/how-do-i-add-some-default-parameters-when-using-restkit-and-rkobjectmanager/11465562#11465562)

Comment: I'll be damned. I've done my fair share of Googling without finding that answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about adding it to queryParams?

```
NSString *resourcePath = [@"/products" stringByAppendingQueryParameters:_queryParams];
```

Where queryParams is a NSMutableDictionary where you add your token.

Comment: Well, what do you know. The simplest solutions are often easily overlooked :)